# Extract bit vector value from Z3 BitVector expr

Tags: ocaml, z3

I have to extract bit vectors from Z3 BitVector expressions that can be up to 1000 bits wide. BitVector.get_int, BitVector.numeral_to_string fail with "Conversion failed" message. I tried extracting bit slices of length 19 (the max get_int seems to tolerate) but get_int doesn't seem to work on extracted bit vectors.

How do I convert large bit vector expressions to bit vectors (i.e. arrays of int)? I am using the OCaml API of Z3 ver 4.4.1.

Thanks!

Comment: BitVector.get_int failing is probably OK, because the result doesn't fit into a 31-bit OCaml int, but the strings should work. Could you open a new issue in our issue tracker, ideally with a replayable exampel? The tracker is here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: Ok, I will create a self contained example when I get the time. In the meanwhile, one solution is to simplify (using Z3.Expr.simplify) after extract and then apply get_int.